# Insert empty space between decoRule and figure

Tags: graphics, chemfig, decorations

I wanted to insert a little space between the figure and the line of \decoRule. Instead \vspace{} is adding a space between the line and the caption. Does anyone know a why it does that?
Thanks.

EDIT:
Answer of leandris works in this minimum example, but fails once i implement the code in my thesis file (pic below).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace the `\vspace{5pt}` command with an empty line, you get the following output:

[image]

Comment: @leandris Thanks you. For some reason this did not came to my mind.

Comment: @leandris Hello!I just found out that your solution works in the minimum example above but once I copy the code into my thesis file the problems remain. Do you have any suggestions why?